odd behavior when using gulp with Deno 2
Now that Deno 2 supports npm, I'm trying to use gulp in Deno 2. But I'm getting odd behavior that's causing me to doubt this will work. I'll provide the list of steps I used later, but first, here's my gulpfile.js and the behavior I'm seeing:
import {series} from 'gulp';

// ----------------------------

export const clean = (cb) => {
    console.log("CLEANING UP");
    cb();
    }

export const compile = (cb) => {
    console.log("COMPILING");
    cb();
    }

export const build = (cb) => {
    series(clean, compile);
    cb();
    }

Using git bash shell:
$ gulp clean
[08:53:17] Using gulpfile ~\gulp\gulpfile.js
[08:53:17] Starting 'clean'...
CLEANING UP
[08:53:17] Finished 'clean' after 3.34 ms

$ gulp compile
[08:53:26] Using gulpfile ~\gulp\gulpfile.js
[08:53:26] Starting 'compile'...
COMPILING
[08:53:26] Finished 'compile' after 2.5 ms

$ gulp build
[08:53:30] Using gulpfile ~\gulp\gulpfile.js
[08:53:30] Starting 'build'...
[08:53:30] Finished 'build' after 3.03 ms

As you can see, when running the tasks named 'clean' and 'compile', text is output to the console. However, when running the tasks via the series() function, nothing is output to the terminal. That makes me wonder whether the individual tasks are running at all.
Here are the steps I used in the git bash shell, starting in my home directory:
$ mkdir gulp
$ cd gulp
$ deno init
$ npm install -g gulp-cli    // unless you already have gulp's CLI installed
$ deno install npm:gulp

Then, create the gulpfile.js above and run gulp tasks as above.
One thing I thought was odd, and may be a clue, is that even before running deno install npm:gulp, thus installing gulp locally in my project, executing gulp --version produced:
$ gulp --version
CLI version: 3.0.0
Local version: 5.0.0

I did not expect to see a local version since I was creating a brand new project in a brand new folder.
(feel free to stop reading if you wish) Why use gulp with Deno in the first place?
Answer: I want to define my tasks in code, i.e. JavaScript, TypeScript, or in my case civet. Using Deno's tasks key in my deno.json file is painful unless your tasks are extremely simple. It would be great if I could do that directly in my deno.json file, but JSON doesn't allow functions as values. Personally, I think that JSON sucks. JSONC is a bit of an improvement since it allows comments and trailing commas, but still doesn't allow functions. I wish that Deno allowed me to just create a deno.js file - or deno.ts if you prefer. It could easily check that, e.g. functions as values only appear under the "tasks" key, that necessary permissions have been granted, etc. Then (if e.g. functions series(), parallel(), etc. were provided) there'd be no need for an external build system.

Forgot to mention that I set the global env variable NODE_OPTIONS to '--disable-warning=ExperimentalWarning'. Otherwise, you'll get a bunch of warnings about require() being used to load an ESM module is an experimental feature. But the behavior described should still appear.

Your question doesn't quite follow the standard guidelines. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a great question, increasing your chance to get an actual answer.

Reacting to the last paragraph of your question, it's worth noting that Deno 2.1 has introduced task dependencies, which allows for more complex task definitions directly in the deno.json file. This feature enables developers to define dependencies between tasks, ensuring that certain tasks are executed before others.
For example, you can create a script that solves the problem you outlined and then run it as a dependency by specifying deno task.ts command in the deno.json file. This approach can help you achieve the desired behavior, albeit indirectly.
